# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" for convert string given from edit text to long

Tags: java, android

I want to give a number from edit text and convert to Long and payment this number with a bank gate.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.otherpay);

    pardakht = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pardakhtbutton);
    mablagh = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mablagh);
    varizi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed4);
    description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
    descriptionvariz = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed5);


        mablaghs = varizi.getText().toString();
        //convert number to long
        mandeh = Long.parseLong(mablaghs);


    //online pay formoney
    pardakht.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                myPeyment(mandeh);

        }
    });
```

and I have an eroor:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ir.atzgroup.atzsoft/ir.atzgroup.atzsoft.OtherpayActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

I have to convert my string that given from edit text to Long to payment
please help me

Comment: Check the value of `mablaghs`. It is `""`

Comment: You should also tell us what the (text) number was which caused the exception.  Assuming it be something too large to fit into a `Long`, then consider using `BigDecimal` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the input only when user clicks on the Button because at the time of initialization value will be "".

Code:

```
 //online pay formoney
    pardakht.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                try{ 
                mandeh = Long.parseLong(varizi.getText().toString());
                myPeyment(mandeh);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                  //Invalid input entered.
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Error says `For input string: ""`

You cannot convert empty `String` to Number. So you need to handle this at the code level.

```
 if(!mablaghs.isEmpty())
   mandeh = Long.parseLong(mablaghs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before parsing by `Long.parseLong(mablaghs)`, you should check entered text is a number by using the below method.

```
 boolean digitsOnly = TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(editText.getText()); 

 if (digitsOnly) {
     mandeh = Long.parseLong(mablaghs);
 }
```